# xml feed - automatically process - find incorrect URL

Tags: xml

I have xml product feed from ecommerce store and there is more than 5000 products. The feed is consist of let's say classic information like - title, description, price, image, category, ...

There are somewhere maybe 10 product with URL adress with an image that does not load (the image was probably uploaded into product somehow incorrectly).

I am looking for solution that would give me automatic way to go throught all of the images and check if the image is loaded or not loaded (not loaded images don't give back 404 page).

Thanks for help guys.

Comment: Can you please share your code or approach what you have tried till now.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for incomplete question. Let's have this feed: https://www.huskycz.cz/exporty/feed_shopy.xml and I know, that couple of image URLS in the <image></image> are not loading (because these images were incorrectly uploaded into product). I need to find those products and edit them in administration ...

Comment: Can you also share any image url which does not load for your XML? I tried to check a few random ones and I could see images in them. Also you could check to see 404 error or size of the loaded image, if size is 0 bytes then there is no image in it. You can use any XML Parser to check image one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the below code in Java using JAXB and ImageIO. JAXB to parse the XML and ImageIO for checking if image exists or not. I am not sure if you are a Java Person but same logic might apply for other languages as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:\\DocuApi\\imageDemoApp\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\feed_shopy.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.stack.image.dto");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnMarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            System.out.println("Parsed XML successfully");

            List<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> nonImageList = new ArrayList<String>();


            SHOP shop = (SHOP)jaxbUnMarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            List<SHOPITEM> shopItems = shop.getSHOPITEM();
            for(SHOPITEM shopItem: shopItems){
                IMAGES images = shopItem.getIMAGES();
                List<String> imageURIs = images.getIMAGE();
                for(String imguri: imageURIs){
                    Image image;
                    try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imguri));
                        if(image != null){

                            imageList.add(imguri);
                        }else{
                            nonImageList.add(imguri);
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                        nonImageList.add(imguri);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        nonImageList.add(imguri);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Size of imageList is- " + imageList.size());
            System.out.println("Size of nonImageList is- " + nonImageList.size());
            for(String imageUrl: nonImageList){
                System.out.println("NonImage URL " + imageUrl);
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```